# Button Image states: Png files disappear when clicked

Tags: html, css, button, mobile, png

Hello to the Stackoverflow community, I'm having a hard time figuring this out, I'm using css to change the states of a button from normal/ clicked/ hover.

Heres my HTML, simply the div layer where the button sits

```
<div id="newsarticle"><a href="/twitter.html" id="button-twitter"></a></div>
```

Heres my css

```
/*Twitter */
#button-twitter {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 20px;
background:url('../images/btns/quicklinks-normalState-twitter.png'); no-repeat top;
        }                   
#button-twitter:hover {
background:url('../images/btns/quicklinks-hoverState-twitter.png') no-repeat top;
}
#button-twitter:active {
background: url('../images/btns/quicklinks-clickedState-twitter.png') no-repeat top;
/*Twitter */
```

What happens on Mobile and the Ipad is that when you click, you switch to the active state and then that simply disappears, you wait a moment with a missing button until you go to the next page.

This does not happen on desktops mobile and ipads only, does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What I think may be happening here is the click event on the mobile device isn't being fired quickly enough (before the action request on the link). I would recommend adding this to your body:

```
   <body ontouchstart="">
    ...
   </body>
```

Alternatively there is a small JS library called [Fastclick](http://labs.ft.com/2011/08/fastclick-native-like-tapping-for-touch-apps/) that you could look into.

Comment: Unfortuantly that doesn't help but I can see where your going with it, I also thought it was somthing similar, just not sure what to add!

Comment: I do know that the :hover pseudo class does not work on the apple devices unless you specifically define your own functionality using javascript. You could try applying ontouchstart to the div itself.